# How to show $\vdash (\neg\neg p \rightarrow p)$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

Given these axioms: where $\phi, \psi, \theta$ are formulas

$$ 1.:(\psi \rightarrow (\theta \rightarrow \psi))$$
$$ 2.: ((\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \theta) \rightarrow (\theta \rightarrow \psi))$$

And using the deduction theorem.

So I started with trying to show that $\neg\neg p \vdash p$ (so I can use deduction theorem later).

From this:

1.$\neg\neg p$ Assumption

2.$(\neg\neg p \rightarrow (\neg\neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg p))$ Axiom #1

3.$(\neg \neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg p)$ 1,2 MP.

4.$((\neg \neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg p) \rightarrow (\neg p \rightarrow \neg p))$ Axiom #2

5.$(\neg p \rightarrow \neg p)$ 3, 4 MP.

6.$((\neg p \rightarrow \neg p) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow p))$ Axiom #2

7.$(p\rightarrow p)$ 5,6 MP.

I'm stuck here though, I have no idea how to proceed any further... Any hints?

Comment: I'm confused. What are you asking about, is it $\neg\neg p \vdash p$ or $\vdash \neg\neg p \to p$? And do you want a formal proof or can you use the deduction theorem? **Edit:** Nevermind, I understood now. You want a formal proof of $\neg\neg p \vdash p$ to later use the deduction theorem to construct a formal proof of $\vdash \neg\neg p \to p$.

Comment: I do apologize, it's my first time taking a course in logic. I'm asking about $\vdash (\neg\neg p \rightarrow p)$. From my understanding, the deduction theorem says: $\vdash (\neg\neg p \rightarrow p)$ iff $\neg\neg p \vdash p$ correct? So I thought if you can show that $\neg\neg p \vdash p$ then that means $\vdash \neg \neg p \rightarrow p$ but it seems as that's not the case.

Comment: You are correct and that is exactly the case. But meta-proving $\vdash \neg \neg p \rightarrow p$ is not the same as giving a formal proof of $\vdash \neg \neg p \rightarrow p$. Now I'm confused again as whether to you want a formal proof or not.

Comment: I apologize then, if that's the case. I do want some sort of a formal proof using the deduction theorem and the 2 axioms. EDIT: Also thank you for clarifying that meta-proving $\vdash (\neg\neg p \rightarrow p)$ is not the same as giving a formal proof of $\vdash (\neg\neg p \rightarrow p)$!

Comment: You can't have a formal proof and still use the deduction theorem. Using the deduction theorem is... using a theorem. A formal proof can only use the axioms and modus ponens (I'm assuming MP is your only rule).

Comment: Wait. Can I clarify something? If I show that $\neg\neg p \vdash p$, then can I use the deduction theorem to deduce that $\vdash (\neg\neg p \rightarrow p)$? If so, then yes. That's what I wanted to do in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you can. Are you sure about the axioms, though? I don't see a proof at the moment. Going to bed now. Il'l try again tomorrow if no one answers in the mean time.

Comment: @Raymond: Your last comment is correct, this is a proper application of the DT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\neg \neg p \rightarrow (\neg \neg \neg \neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg p)$$
$$\neg \neg \neg \neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg p$$
$$(\neg \neg \neg \neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg p)\rightarrow 
(\neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg \neg p)$$
$$\neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg \neg p$$
$$(\neg p \rightarrow \neg \neg \neg p)\rightarrow (\neg\neg p \rightarrow p)$$
$$\neg\neg p \rightarrow p$$
$$p$$

Comment: Wow, that's something I didn't expect. Thank you!

Comment: Summary in words, for those to whom it's helpful: From the assumed truth of $\lnot \lnot p$ you can deduce $\lnot \lnot \lnot \lnot p \to \lnot \lnot p$. From there, apply the contrapositive rule twice to peel off two layers of negation (and reverse the direction of implication twice, a no-op), giving you $\lnot \lnot p \to p$. From this and the assumed truth of $\lnot \lnot p$, deduce $p$. By the deduction theorem, if you can prove $c$ assuming $h$, you can also prove $h \to c$.