# Show that $(\phi \rightarrow \psi), (\phi \rightarrow \neg \psi) \vdash \neg \phi$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to show that $(\phi \rightarrow \psi), (\phi \rightarrow \neg \psi) \vdash \neg \phi$ using the axioms: For any formula $\psi,\theta, \phi$ $$ 1.:(\psi \rightarrow (\theta \rightarrow \psi))$$
$$2.:(\psi \rightarrow (\phi\rightarrow\theta)) \rightarrow((\psi\rightarrow\phi)\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\theta)))$$
$$3.: ((\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \theta) \rightarrow (\theta \rightarrow \psi))$$

I'm allowed to use Thinning Rule, Contradiction and Deduction.

Looking at this, I'm thinking this has to be by contradiction. But I have no idea how to start this.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Can't you use that $\lnot \lnot \phi \rightarrow \phi$?

Comment: You can prove ALL $\rightarrow$, $\lnot$ tautologies from this axiom set using just deduction (or modus ponens or detachment).  Note that (($\phi$ $\rightarrow$ $\psi$) $\rightarrow$ (($\phi$ $\rightarrow$ $\lnot$ $\psi$) $\rightarrow$ $\lnot$ $\phi$)) is a tautology.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: so modus ponens (and substitution I suppose) also are allowed, not only the three axioms?

Answer (score 2):

In your previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953398/how-to-show-vdash-neg-neg-p-rightarrow-p) you have proved *Double Negation elimination* :

> $\vdash (¬¬p → p)$

with axioms 1 and 3; so we assume that we can use it.

We assume also the *Proof by contradiction* theorem :

> If $\Gamma, ¬φ \vdash ψ$ and $\Gamma, ¬φ \vdash ¬ψ$, then $\Gamma \vdash φ$.

---

*Proof*

*1)* $(φ → ψ)$ --- assumed

*2)* $(φ → ¬ψ)$ --- assumed

*3)* $\vdash \lnot \lnot φ → φ$ --- *DN*

*4)* $(φ → ψ), \lnot \lnot φ \vdash ψ$ - from 3) by *modus ponens*

*5)* $(φ → ¬ψ), \lnot \lnot φ \vdash ¬ψ$ - from 3) by *modus ponens*

Now we apply *Thinning* and then *Proof by contradiction* to 4) and 5) with $\Gamma = \{ (φ → ψ), (φ → ¬ψ) \}$ to derive :

> *6)* $ (φ → ψ), (φ → ¬ψ) \vdash \lnot φ$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem fairly quickly using [Prover9](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/gui/v05.html).  All you need to do comes as to use the graphical interface, and put in the following as your assumptions... note you do need the periods:

```
1. -P(x->y) | -P(x) | P(y).
```

Via this axiom and the rule of hyperresolution this enables you to accurately interpret steps in the proof to behave just like applications of condensed detachment.  The "-" is negation like your $\lnot$ symbol.

```
2. P(x->(y->x)).

3. P((x->(y->z))->((x->y)->(x->z))).

4. P((-x->-y)->(y->x)).
```

And put this as the goal:

```
P((x->y)->((x->-y)->-x)).
```

"P" you can interpret as meaning $\vdash$.  Thus, once you have  $\vdash$((x->y)->((x->-y)->-x)), if you assume (x->y) as well as (x->-y), you can detach -x as desired.

Answer (score 0):

We first prove a general case:

$\{P\rightarrow Q, P\rightarrow R\}\vdash P\rightarrow Q\wedge R$

Now, the proof is as follows:

$$\begin{array}{r|ll}
(1) & P\rightarrow Q & Hyp.\\ (2) & P\rightarrow R & Hyp.\\ (3) & (Q\rightarrow(R\rightarrow(Q\wedge R)) & Theorem\\ (4) & P\rightarrow(R\rightarrow(Q\wedge R)) & (1), (3), HS\\(5) &(P\rightarrow(R\rightarrow(Q\wedge R))\rightarrow((P\rightarrow R)\rightarrow(P\rightarrow(Q\wedge R)) & Ax. 2\\ (6) & (P\rightarrow R)\rightarrow(P\rightarrow(Q\wedge R)) & (4),(5), MP\\ (7) & P\rightarrow(Q\wedge R) & (2), (6), MP
\end{array}$$
Now, replacing $R$ by $\neg Q$ we get $\{P\rightarrow Q,P\rightarrow\neg Q\}\vdash P\rightarrow(Q\wedge\neg Q)$, which is equivalent with $P\rightarrow\bot$, and this is equivalent with $\neg P$; Using $\vdash(Q\wedge \neg Q)\leftrightarrow\bot$ and $\vdash\neg P\leftrightarrow\bot$.